# Can I get dataset of google queries asked by people in a particular time period?

Tags: data-request, internet

I am doing a research on how queries have evolved over time(focusing on google mainly). I want to compare what queries people searched on google last year and compare it to what they are searching right now.( I want raw query and not abstracted data on topics most searched like google trends) I went through all the option mentioned in this [answer](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-large-datasets-open-to-the-public) on quora including google's bigquery dataset but couldn't find appropriate dataset. Can anyone guide me in this regard?

Comment: Why would Google release this personal information (for free I suppose)?

Comment: Google has already open sourced many of its project to push the research in that area or maybe sometime public welfare. Here I am not asking for all the info, companies have been releasing data anonymously(so can't relate that data to any particular used) to allow people to research on that dataset.

Comment: Why you won't get non-aggregated search results - the infamous AOL example - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOL_search_data_leak

Comment: It seems you need Google trends